# when this code didn't run,the next line code begin to run

Tags: python, pytorch

How to control this line code finished running, the next line begin to run.

```
import flask
import os

def start_predictor():
    os.system("python ok.py")
    os.system("python finish.py")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn", True)
    predictor_server = mp.Process(target=start_predictor)
    predictor_server.deamon = True
    predictor_server.start()
```

I used to add time.sleep(10), althouth it worked, I think it's trouble, this code didn't take me 10 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

use subprocess

```
p = subprocess.Popen('test.exe')
p.wait()
```